# Cassini ignoring Win NT role authorization, IIS 7.5 all ok

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, impersonation, roleprovider

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application running on both my local dev box (Win7) and staging server (W2k8r2).  The application operates fine in both environments until ASP.NET Windows authorization security is enabled.

After securing the web-app, it continues operates correctly on the staging server but generates 401.2 access denied's on my local dev box. The only significant difference I can see is on local dev box, I'm using Cassini via Visual Studio whereas the server is IIS7.5.

Windows authorization + impersonation is being used. What could cause Cassini to generate these 401.2 access denied?

Web.config is:

```
<system.web>
   <authentication mode="Windows" />
   <identity impersonate="true" />
   <!-- replication of system.webServer security settings for cassini which doesn't process them... -->
   <authorization>
       <allow roles=".\Test Application - Users" />
       <deny users="*" />
   </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
   <security>
      <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
          <add accessType="Allow" users="" roles="Test Application - Users" />
      </authorization>
  </security>
```

FYI Relevant users are in the 'Test Application - Users' Windows security group on each system.

**Solution**

The underlying issue on the dev box turned out to be that:

1. Cassini doesn't support identity impersonation **and**
2. Whilst the user *had* been added to relevant NT groups, they had not logged off/on and thus the group SID's associated with their Windows token had not been refreshed

If impersonation had been supported by Cassini I doubt this would have been an issue because a new token would have been established within the impersonation context. Thanks to @x0n for pointing in the right direction.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure, but I don't think cassini can impersonate (iis express can, however.)

Comment: @x0n - you seem to be correct. Posted an answer to my own question below which is related to your comment

Comment: ok, if you don't mind, I'll whore the points by duping my comment as an answer which you can accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not entirely sure, but I don't think cassini can impersonate (iis express can, however.)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. The underlying issue on the dev box turned out to be that:

(1). Cassini doesn't support identity impersonation and 

(2) Whilst the user had been added to relevant NT groups, they had not logged off/on and thus the group SID's associated with their Windows token had not been refreshed

If impersonation had been supported by Cassini I doubt this would have been an issue because a new token would have been established within the impersonation context.

Answer (score 0):

In solution explorer pane **select the Web Project and hit F4**. (not right click+properties, thats different) - this will show property pane

In properties Pane then set:
**Windows Authentication**: Enable
**Anonymous Authentication**: Disabled

Run your project, Happy Days!